Distort object coordinates into a spiral
Good day guys, I'm failing misserably on distorting the coordinates for a texture in a spiral pattern for an object, my target is to display a spiral of clouds onto a sphere, and those clouds to look like a spiral wrapping around it, in a faction similar to the one in the picture 
Could someone better in trigonometry than me provide an idea on how to perform this?
Thanks in advance

I reckon you're fine with seams between the marked lines marking the flow of the spiral? You can't stretch the coordinate space to be side-by side with space that is one circumference before/after without a seam or some extreme, ugly stretching in the opposite direction to the main stretch direction.

Alternatively, you don't want to change the coordinate space at all, which is the X in XY problem whereas the real problem, Y, as described, is just to make clouds following a spiral...

To achieve what you want, you may do as little as shifting the texture coordinate upwards based on angle - I'm using the UV map, because the UV sphere already has the azimuthal angle unwrapped to $U$ (x) axis.
The generated "Color Grid" texture puts one caption per each 128×128 pixel square, so as I'm using a default 1024×1024 dimensions texture, I have 8 rows (8×128 = 1024) in the texture, therefore in order to align the captions after the shift, one needs to  shift by a multiple of one row: ⅛ or 0.125 of the height:

Imgur mirror (SE image hosting has problems)
I'm adjusting the effect to the texture to look nicely but any vertical displacement will do, question is just what is the climbing rate of the spiral you want. On the GIF above I shifted by two rows (0.125 × 2 = 0.25) so that the alternating row coloring matches:

Imgur mirror
The shearing happens where the UV seam already was, so you don't get any additional seam, and any seamless logic you would use on normal UV map of a UV sphere, you also have to apply here, just with an adequate $V$ offset (here the two rows offset).
You can however recalculate the texture coordinate to have a single strip, that then has the seams on the edges of that strip, where its glued together to self; remember to change texture to adequate, here I divided the height by 8 (to get only one row) and multiplied by 8 (to keep the same area), resulting with 8192×128 texture:

Imgur Mirror
Where the old seam used to be, there are still color grid cell boundaries just because of my exact maths, but you could for example animate the texture by adding #frame/1000 to the x coordinate, and then you would see it is in fact continuous:

Imgur mirror
Now let's adjust some values to be able to go back to a square texture as likely you will use one (and generated textures are square):

Imgur mirror
Isolate the logic as a custom group because it will be needed twice:

Imgur mirror
And now it's easy to generate two strips, one based on modified original coordinate by half of a row so that one strip overlaps the seam of the other. Using ping-pong to get a smooth edge on that top (actually bottom in nodes) strip, it can smoothly mix with the bottom while covering the seam. I purposefully only stretch one strip's coordinate to make it more visible:

Imgur mirror

Imgur mirror

Great! thank you
